# Simple SQL Query problem: how to only "select" items from table_A which are also in table_B

Tags: sql

This is the query I have been using in sqlite / python:

```
Select wbCode from CountriesList_A
```

but I would like to have some sort of IF statement to only return me the items which are ALSO in CountriesListB.

Suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just join to the other table using an inner join, which only returns rows that are present in both tables.

```
SELECT a.wbCode
FROM CountriesList_A a
INNER JOIN CountriesList_B b ON a.wbCode = b.wbCode
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
select wbCode 
from CountriesList_A 
where wbCode in (select wbCode from CountriesListB)
```

Comment: Why use a sub query instead of a join?

Comment: No particular reason.  Joins tend to confuse people so depending how people ask makes me think of one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
 Select * From tableA A
 Where Exists 
     (Select * From Table B
      Where wbCode = A.wbCode )
```

Comment: Why use a sub query instead of a join?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.wbCode from CountriesList_A a
WHERE EXISTS (
  select b.wbCode 
  FROM CountriesListB b
  WHERE a.wbCode = b.wbCode)
```

Or

```
Select a.wbCode from CountriesList_A a
WHERE a.wbCode IN (
  select b.wbCode 
  FROM CountriesListB b)
```

Or

```
Select a.wbCode 
from CountriesList_A a inner join CountriesListB b 
  on a.wbCode = b.wbCode
```

Comment: Why use a sub query instead of a join?